# load balancer for proxy forwarders

Tags: nginx, proxy, load-balancing, haproxy, squid

I have some pool of proxies. I need to create proxy rotator for my software.

APP > proxy rotator > proxy > http/https.

I was trying to use nginx upstream but unfortunately nginx is reverse proxy not transparent proxy forwarder. Can you give me some ideas how to achieve proxy rotator?

I cannot add proxy rotator to APP (too complexe code).

Answer (score 0):

**Nginx** is good to reverse proxy job or web server, to proxy job the better is **Squid**.

You can read load balancing in Squid documentation

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/LoadBalance